# PHP mysqli inserts row double while I want it to insert once

Tags: php, mysql

So I am working on this register system. And it happens to put the user double in the mysql table. While I only request the page once. I'm sending a request to `http://localhost/highfive/inc/php/functions.php?method=register&response=RECAPTCHA_RESPONSE&username=USERNAME_HERE&email=EMAIL_HERE&password=PASSWORD_HERE`. And I only make this request once. But somehow it puts the user double in the table. Here is my php:

```php
function connectdb() {
    try {
        return new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die(json_encode(array("success"=>false, "message"=>"Something went wrong on our end, please try again later.")));
    }
}

function firedb($conn, $sql, $method = "SELECT") {
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($method == "SELECT") {
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $results = array();
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                array_push($results, $row);
            }
            return $results;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            $conn->query($sql);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['method'])) {
    if ($_GET['method'] == "register") {
        if (!isset($_GET['response']) || !isset($_GET['username']) || !isset($_GET['email']) || !isset($_GET['password'])) {
            die(json_encode(array("success"=>false, "message"=>"One or more parameters are not given.")));
        }
        if (!filter_var($_GET['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            die(json_encode(array("success"=>false, "message"=>"Email address is not valid.")));
        }
        $conn = connectdb();
        $response = $_GET['response'];
        $username = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$_GET['username'])));
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['password']);
        $email = $_GET['email'];
        $a = firedb($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username`='".strtolower($username)."' OR `email`='".strtolower($email)."'");
        if ($a != false) {
            die(json_encode(array("success"=>false, "message"=>"There is already an user registered with this email address or username.")));
        }
        if (firedb($conn, "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, ip) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '".GetIP()."')", "INSERT")) {
            die(json_encode(array("success"=>true, "message"=>"Logged in! Redirecting you to the login page...")));
        } else {
            die(json_encode(array("success"=>false, "message"=>"Something went wrong on our end, please try again later.")));
        }
    }
}
```

When I saw that it put the user double in the table, I tried refreshing the page, seeing if it would add more, but then it returns `{"success":false,"message":"There is already an user registered with this email address or username."}`

> The problem is that the code puts the record double in the table, while I only want it once in there.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are running your queries twice if method is NOT "SELECT" in your firedb() function. First at start in the function (1.line) and then second time in your else statements.

Comment: Ah thank you @Ogreucha I didnt see that at all. Thanks!

Comment: Use mysqli prepared statements to avoid sql injection. Don't store passwords as plain text, use PHP functions password_hash and password_verify

Comment: @nacho Yes, I know. But right now its just me testing stuff in my localhost